# POST form in MVC - No Values being written to DB

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a model that I'm trying to edit with a form:

```
public class Basiclife
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ResponseId { get; set; }
    public string Plantype { get; set; }
    public int Enrolledftes { get; set; }
    public decimal Pctemployer { get; set; }
    public decimal Fixedbenamt { get; set; }
    public decimal Salarymult { get; set; }
    public decimal Bencap { get; set; }
}
```

And a view wrapper to edit it (with the editor in a separate partial view):

```
<h2>CreateBasicLifeResponse</h2>
<div id="planList">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("CreateBasicLifeResponse", "Surveys"))
    {
        <div id="editorRows">
            @foreach (var item in Model.basiclives)
            {
                @Html.Partial("_BasicLifeResponse", item)
            }
        </div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Add", "BasicLifeResponse", null, new { id = "addItem", @class = "button" });
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    }

</div>
```

The wrapper's model is:

```
public class ResponseBasicLife
{
    public Response response { get; set; }
    public List<Basiclife> basiclives { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the partial view:

```
@using CustomSurveyTool.Models
@model Basiclife

<div class="editorRow">
    @using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("basiclives"))
    {
    <div class="form-horizontal">


        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Plantype, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Plantype, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Plantype, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Enrolledftes, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Enrolledftes, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Enrolledftes, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Pctemployer, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Pctemployer, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Pctemployer, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Fixedbenamt, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Fixedbenamt, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Fixedbenamt, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Salarymult, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Salarymult, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Salarymult, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Bencap, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Bencap, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Bencap, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <a href="#" class="deleteRow">X</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    }
</div>
```

Here's my controller action where I'm getting the proper responseId and assigning it to the form values:

```
         public ActionResult CreateBasicLifeResponse(ResponseBasicLife model)
    {

        for (var i = 1; i < model.basiclives.Count; i++)
        {
            string currentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            Response targetresponse = db.response.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Userid == currentUserId);
            int responseid = targetresponse.Id;
            model.basiclives[i].ResponseId = responseid;
            db.basiclife.Add(model.basiclives[i]);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        ResponseBasicLife basicliferesponse = new ResponseBasicLife
        {
            basiclives = new List<Basiclife>
            {
                new Basiclife {  }
            }
        };
        return View(basicliferesponse);
    }
```

The only thing that's being written to the database is the ResponseID. How do I get the rest of the values to write to it?

Comment: Is the `basiclife` object populated in the request?

Comment: @nurdyguy I think you're asking if the partial view uses the basiclife model, which it does. I've added the code above. I'm a complete newbie so if that doesn't answer your question, lmk

Comment: I'm asking if the information is actually getting to the controller.  Put a breakpoint at the first line of the method and see what is in the variable.

Comment: The code you have shown works fine.

Comment: Have tried using Chrome Dev Tools or something to examine the payload being sent back to the server?

Answer (score 0):

This is a unique case where [EditorFor](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETMVCDisplayTemplateAndEditorTemplatesForEntityFrameworkDbGeographySpatialTypes.aspx) could help. Essentially an object will have its editor template which is kind of like a partial view but specific to editing forms.

Secondly, the being form you are specifying is expecting the model of the view that you specified - in your case the viewWrapper. If for instance you specified a `List<BasicLife>`, then that is what the postBack shall be expecting, and not the `BasicLife` object. Below is how your postback would look like.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateBasicLifeResponse(List<BasicLife> model){
      //your code goes here
}
```

From your view though, it looks clear that `Model` contains more than just a list. That is what shall be expected from the callback.

Comment: That makes sense. I'm adding my wrapper's model and new controller above.